# Are there any "official" ways to save/load a scikit-learn model to/from plain text like json?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to save any sklearn model to json, and want a scikit-learn's official way for it. Do you have any ideas?

I need this kind of code:

```py
from sklearn.export import json_export
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

clf = RandomForestClassifier().fit(X, y)

with open("model.json", "w") as f:
    json_export(clf, f)
```

Comment: Serialisation to json does not appear to be a standard part of sklearn, but like most objects in Python, you could probably get your specific case serialised in a robust way, similar to what the person in this article is doing: https://cmry.github.io/notes/serialize

Comment: Serialize ensemble model is hard stuff than just LogisticRegression, but anyway, thanks for commenting. I just understand that scikit-learn has no feature of serializing models.

Comment: Can you explain more about your use-case? If you only want to use the model again in python then [official way is `joblib`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html#persistence-example). If something else, then maybe go with `PMML`.

Comment: Why is OP being downvoted? It's clearly a programing question, at first glance there is nothing towards this matter in the official docs, and there are other machine learning libraries that behave exactly like OP expected scikit-learn to behave (pomegranate comes to mind).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is unfortunately no official way for that in sklearn.
Use pickle/joblib to serialize the classifier Python object, or implement your own JSON serialization for your particular model.
The attributed that are set by training end with _ by convention, but you will also need many of the constructor parameters also.